# More info on Cloud Endpoints return types

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities),

> the return value type cannot be simple type such as String or int. The return value needs to be a POJO, an array or a Collection.

This is exactly how things work on the local dev server. However, once deployed, collections and arrays of primitive types result in a `500 Internal Server Error` whether the `GET` URL is typed into the browser or the APIs explorer is used, despite the fact that server logs show `200 Success`. Collections of POJOs work fine.

This has been the case for months and through several attempts with different methods. Is this the intended behaviour or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I encountered the same thing recently.  I tried returning a collection or array of strings from an endpoint.  It appeared to work - it generated my client code without errors and created code that appeared specifically designed to handle the type (in other words, yes, they meant for it to work).  However, once deployed it didn't work.

Eventually I turned up a SO Q/A from the spring (can't find it now) in which Google became aware of the bug, but I guess they still haven't fixed it or changed the docs.

[edit: I found the post I was thinking of].  In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15457490/150016) from 2013-03, Dan Holevoet of Google initially suggests using a collection of entities, but finds that this doesn't work, so suggests as a work-around that the collection be wrapped in a temporary class.  That, plus my experience above (it generated a StringCollection, as I was attempting to use a collection of strings), is what lead me to conclude that it is a known issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad it's a bug and something that they're working on. In the mean-time, I just return a collection of POJOs, then make an array of one property on the front-end, but this will become increasingly taxing as the size and number on POJOs increases. Also, this bug invalidates your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20112125/1720014).

Comment: Ah, good catch on the  other answer - I will add a correction there.  BTW, I'm not suggesting that they are working on a fix - just that they are aware of it.

Comment: My post that you're referencing refers to method arguments, not return types. Supporting multiple entities in a post body is not going to work (without a wrapper) for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @DanHolevoet I assumed it was the same issue because I created a GET endpoint that returned a List<String>, it generated a client library successfully, but I couldn't get it to work until I added a wrapper.  Should it have worked?

Comment: I think the doc needs to be updated to say "The return value needs to be a POJO or a collection of POJOs."

Comment: And IMO the client code generation should fail - if the return type is not supported.  The code generation error message are much better now - a error during code generation would have saved me lots of time.

Comment: @DanHolevoet Happened to come back to this wondering whether it had been fixed or corrected.  Almost a year and no change has been made to the docs - does this mean that it Google still plans to make it work?