# Google Cloud Endpoints can't return Map (instead it returns JsonMap)

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Google Cloud Endpoints returns a `JsonMap` instead of my server side `Map<Long,Long>`.  **How can I get the `Map<Long,Long>` ?**

On the Google App Engine side I define a Google cloud endpoint that returns a map:

```
@ApiMethod(path="somebendpoint/somename")
public Map<Long, Long> getSomething(@Named("x")int x, User user){
    Map<Long, Long> map = ...   
    return map;
}
```

On the Android client side, I retrieve this with

```
wEndpoint.wEndpoint().getSomething(x).execute();
```

But the return type is a `JsonMap`, which is `Map<String,Object>`.

### ---

--- edit (Wrapping the Map in a wrapper class also doesn't seem to work)

I wrapped Map on the server side in a wrapper class, like this:

```
public class WrapperMap implements Serializable {
    private Map<Long, Long> wrapperMap;
    public WrapperMap(){
    }
    public setMap(Map<Long, Long> map){
        wrapperMap = map;
    }
    public Map<Long, Long> getMap(){
        return wrapperMap;
    }
}
```

but still on the client side, when I do:

WrapperMap temp = wEndpoint.wEndpoint().getSomething(x).execute();

`temp.getMap()` returns a `JsonMap`, not a `Map<Long,Long>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With endpoints you shouldn't have to do the JSON, or de-JSON'ing yourself - endpoints does it for you.  But I think you will need to wrap your map in a class for this to work, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20196518/150016).

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I tried that and still the underlying Map<Long,Long> inside the wrapper ends up being a JsonMap on the Android client side.  It seems like there's something special about a Map?  I'll update my question to include this attemp.

Comment: I think the class also needs to be a bean - so you must have standard setter for wrapperMap, as well as the getter.  But I haven't tried maps myself.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I made my wrapper class a full Java bean (with serialization,setters,getters, etc.) and it still seems only able to return a JsonMap. I updated the question to show the full bean.

Comment: Ok, then it seems to me that there is a problem.  When I call execute on an endpoints that returns a wrapper around a List<>, it correctly returns the wrapper - I don't have to do the de-JSON'ing myself.

Comment: Btw Tom, if it is helpful, a List doesn't need to be wrapped in another class, you can get the list with endpoint.getSomething().execute().getItems() but somehow this doesn't seem to be available for a Map.

Comment: Really?  I tried returning a List<String> and it successfully generated client library but did not function correctly.  After some searching I found others having similar problems and being told to use a wrapper.  But I didn't try the getItems() that you've suggested - will try that next time!  Wish the docs were better.

Comment: As it turns out Tom, this does not work on the App Engine production server, as I have just found out.  It works on the development server though.